# Operator function '>' requires that 'UserRating' conform to 'BinaryInteger' - SwiftUI ObservableObject

Tags: swift, observableobject

First of all - these are my first steps with ObservableObjects and maybe its just a little mistake...

i try to create a rating bar with stars (with a paul hudson tutorial) but with a variable which will be used in more than 2 views, so I need an ObservableObject.

The Rating is created in Rating.swift, will be called in FeedbackView.swift and FeedbackView.swift will be called by TabBar from EKLComplete.swift.

I tried the "Paul Hudson Way" with a @Binding var but my Code did not work the same as in Pauls Tutorial. My views all want to have the variable, which is right - because of the Binding.
In my understanding, the @Binding allows me to share the variable with 2 views, in my case my EKLComplete view also want to know the value, so it must be an ObservableObject, right?

After creating the class:

```
class UserRating : ObservableObject {
    @Published private var rating = 4
}
```

And instantiated the variable with the following code in 3 Views

```
@EnvironmentObject var rating : UserRating
```

[image]

This is my code which throws an error.

```
struct Rating: View {
@EnvironmentObject var rating : UserRating

var label = ""

var maximumRating = 5

var offImage: Image?
var onImage = Image(systemName: "star.fill")

var offColor = Color.gray
var onColor = Color.yellow

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        if label.isEmpty == false {
            Text(label)
        }
        ForEach(1..<maximumRating + 1) { number in
            self.image(for: number)
                ///ERROR 1
                .foregroundColor(number > self.rating ? self.offColor : self.onColor)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.rating = number
                    print("Tap gesture!")
            }
        }
    }     
}
func image(for number: Int) -> Image {
    ///ERROR 2
    if number > rating {
        return offImage ?? onImage
    } else {
        return onImage
    }
}
}
```

I receive the following Errormessage:

> Operator function '>' requires that 'UserRating' conform to
>   'BinaryInteger'

This is not working...
1. Say that my rating is an Int 
2. initialize the rating in my class

```
class UserRating : ObservableObject {
@Published private var rating : Int = 4
}
class UserRating : ObservableObject {
    @Published private var rating = 4
    init(rating: Int) {
        self.rating = rating
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the owning *object* and not the `Int` based property. Try:

```swift
.foregroundColor(number > self.rating.rating ? self.offColor : self.onColor)
```

and:

```swift
if number > rating.rating {
    // do your work
}
```

Also, consider changing the name of your environment object to `userRating` so you don't mix yourself up.

```swift
if number > userRating.rating { }
```

Comment: Thank you! This turns the light on :-) - by the way, nice name :D